# Верстка, не работаю ссылки на мобильном устройстве

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, мобильная-разработка

Вот такой вот сайт http://aeroscop.com/.
Навигация на мобильных устройствах не работает, а именно не переходит по ссылкам при нажатии. Все ссылки настроены из под Wordpress. На декстоп версии ссылки работают нормально.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

посмотрите код страницы, в мобильном меню у вас атрибуты ссылок href=" " -именно поэтому не происходжит перехода а просто обновляется страница...

Comment: Именно, Мобильная версия меню не была подключена через wordpress потому и ссылок нету. Не увидел! Сам нашел но и вам спасибо!)

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите консоль браузера внимательно, у Вас много скриптов не подгружаются, 404 ошибка. Наверняка, один из скриптов за меню отвечает.